# Add many chars in string

Tags: c++, string, char

```
string record;
string container;
cin>>container;
record+=" birthday:"+container[8]+container[9]+'.'+container[5]+container[6]+'.'+container[0]+container[1]+container[2]+container[3];
```

Container contain data in format 1993/12/12, i would like to change it to format like this "birhday:12.12.1993". But when it takes container[8] + container[9] it evaluate to integer value, which is sum of ascii number of this chars. Where i did a mistake, or how should i do it to work?

Comment: `record+=string(" birthday:")+container[8]+...`

Comment: Also consider using `std::stringstream`

Comment: Don't trust the user. She won't enter the numbers in the format you expect. `container[8]` will be something different with "1993/3/2". Split the string with `strtok(container.c_str(), "/")` or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use char array;

```
int main(){
string record;
char container[11];
cin>>container;
record+=string ("birthday: ")+container[8]+container[9]+('.')+container[5]+container[6]+ 
        ('.')+container[0]+container[1]+container[2]+container[3];
std::cout<<record;}
```

Comment: Not only this solution is not idiomatic C++, it is also very insecure, since it is very likely the user will at some point enter more than 11 characters, causing a buffer overflow.